# Comparing the value of a variable prolog

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to compare a **variable** to an **atom**?

Is it possible to compare the **contents** of a variable with an **atom** as shown below?

```
Y = [[cirlce], nextTo [square]].
nth0(1, Y, Op),Op == nextTo, doSomething(circle, square).
```

Comment: `[[circle], nextTo [square]]` is a syntax error, not a valid list. Did you intend a comma after `nextTo`? The answer to your question is "yes". Have you tried it? You can also just write, `nth0(1, Y, nextTo), doSomething(circle, square).`

Comment: Oh yeah, found the answer to my question too.

Comment: It's important to note that if you do, say, `X = circle`, this will succeed if X already has a binding to `circle`, but it will also succeed _and bind X to `circle`_ if X is unbound. For this reason, and because Prolog variables can only be assigned once, we tend not to deal with them as if they are pointers in C, or as if they have "contents."

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be tested as below:

```
Y = [[cirlce], nextTo, [square]],
nth0(1, Y, nextTo), doSomething(circle, square).
```

Matching "nextTo" with the element found at index 1 by nth0/3 and will yield true